# Why does Chrome starts fullscreen?

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen

With Mac OS Mavericks and Chrome 35 : everytime I start my computer, the first time I launch Chrome, it starts in fullscreen mode. If I exit fullscreen, quit Chrome and then restart it, it's normal. If I reboot (I don't check "open my apps on startup") and re-launch, it starts again in fullscreen.

Why does it do this ?

Thanks

## Edit

Actually after further testing, it doesn't always start in fullscreen after a reboot, it seems pretty random.

Comment: Are you actually using the full screen mode in Chrome with some web sites?

Comment: No, I never do, or almost. I never quit chrome while in full screen. Maybe just *after* closing a full-screen video, but not during.

Answer (score 1):

You could perform the following steps:

1. Navigate to **chrome://settings**
2. Press the radio buttons next to **Continue where I left off** and under the **On Startup** header.
3. Reboot as you've tried and it should remain non-fullscreen next time.

Comment: It's already like that :/

Comment: Then select the other option, the first one. To start with the home page.

Comment: Well, first, I *want* to continue where I left off. And second, it doesn't always do that, so I don't see how that would help.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem is by going to chrome settings and signing in with my google credentials... After that it stopped going into full screen mode automatically.